# DPL DynamicPageList MediaWiki Errors - Showing HTML Instead of Links

Tags: mediawiki

Just did a fresh install of MediaWiki and DynamicPageList (DPL) but something is not quite configured right and I am having a hard time figuring out what is off exactly.

Instead of showing links to the pages, it is showing some oddly formatted HTML code like this:

`<html><a href="/tjos/index.php/Bird_Dog_Daily_Checklist" title="Bird Dog Daily Checklist">Bird Dog Daily Checklist</a></html>`

If I view source, it actually looks like this:

`<li>&lt;html&gt;&lt;a href="/tjos/index.php/Bird_Dog_Daily_Checklist" title="Bird Dog Daily Checklist"&gt;Bird Dog Daily Checklist&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</li>`

Any ideas on why it is doing that and how to fix it so that it works right?

Answer (score 2):

James, I find a way to fix this. that's because some html tags are forbidden by wiki. we can add "$wgRawHtml=true" into LocalSettings.php.
for more information,please see:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be caused by a change in MediaWiki 1.16. See http://semeb.com/dpldemo/index.php?title=Issue:DPL_incompatible_with_MW_1.16_alpha.

I tried adding $wgRawHtml=true to my LocalSettings.php. It causes the wiki to break (servor error 500).